# Reset auto_increment based on datetime column

Tags: mysql, datetime, auto-increment, reset

I'm working with MySQL through phpMyAdmin. I need to reset the ID fields in one of the tables in my database, but I need to do it based on the publication date of each row. I've been looking everywhere and I can't seem to find a solution :(

The following lines of code work fine, but do not do exactly what I require based on the datetime column:

```
SET @count = 0;
UPDATE `table_name` SET `table_name`.`ID` = @count:= @count + 1;
```

So this is what I have:

```
+----+---------------------+
| ID | post_date           |
+----+---------------------+
| 1  | 2013-11-04 20:06:28 |
| 2  | 2012-03-30 11:20:22 |
| 3  | 2014-06-26 22:59:51 |
+----+---------------------+
```

And this is what I need:

```
+----+---------------------+
| ID | post_date           |
+----+---------------------+
| 1  | 2005-08-02 16:51:48 |
| 2  | 2005-08-02 16:59:36 |
| 3  | 2005-08-02 17:01:54 |
+----+---------------------+
```

Thanks in advance, guys :)

Comment: Dont mess with autocrement ID columns in a database. If your want to see you data in `post_date` order then add an `ORDER by post_date` to your queries, and index the `post_date`. Tables are normally linked using the ID columns. If you amend the ID in one table you will likely **destroy** the relationship to one or more other tables

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @RiggsFolly, but I'm migrating content from another database, so there's no need for me to worry about destroying relationships between tables because there are none for the moment. If you can give me a hand on what I'm trying to achieve, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Ok if you insist, look up [INSERT.. SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: I have almost no knowledge on MySQL, mate. And this kind of websites hasn't been made for that kind of answers. A fully detailed answer would be very much appreciated ;)

Comment: @RiggsFolly with foreign keys and on update cascade you can keep relationships.

Comment: @D'Tails for the record you simply forgot `order by post_date` at the end of your original query. It should have been as follows: `SET @count = 0;
UPDATE table_name SET table_name.ID = @count:= @count + 1 order by post_date;` As said above you can even keep relationships with foreign keys. On the contrary this query will fail if you have fk having on cascade SET to NO ACTION on this field. Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, a simple approach though.

> But you will lose all the relations to other tables since you are
>   resetting the PRIMARY `ID` Keys.

```
# Copy entire table to a temporary one based on the publication date
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#temp_table` AS SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` ORDER BY `post_date`;

# Drop `ID` column from the temporary table
ALTER TABLE `#temp_table` DROP COLUMN `ID`;

# Reset the table `wp_posts` as well as its `ID`
TRUNCATE TABLE `wp_posts`;

# Exclude `ID` column in the INSERT statement below
INSERT INTO  `wp_posts`(`post_author`, `post_date`, ..., `comment_count`) SELECT * FROM `#temp_table`;

# Remove the temporary table
DROP TABLE `#temp_table`;
```

Also see the ERD for WP3.0 below,
[image]

Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description/3.3

Comment: Thanks a lot, @kolunar! It did just what I needed and in a much simpler way. It's a little little problematic having to write down every column's name, but it is still quite a useful way to achieve what I needed, and it only took half an hour of processing time. Again, thanks a lot, mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it with the following script. It selects every row of your table and orders the rows by its date ascending. Then your Update-Command will be executed within a loop.

Add the type of the ID of your table to the DECLARE-Statement and change the 
field-Name in the UPDATE-Statement to your ID-Column name.

```
 BEGIN
        DECLARE col_id BIGINT;
        DECLARE stepLoopDone BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
        DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 1;

        DECLARE ORDER_CURSOR CURSOR FOR

            SELECT id
            FROM wp_posts
            ORDER BY post_date ASC;

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET stepLoopDone = TRUE;
        OPEN ORDER_CURSOR;

        myLoop: LOOP
            FETCH ORDER_CURSOR INTO col_id;

            IF stepLoopDone THEN
                LEAVE myLoop;
            END IF;

            /*YOUR UPDATE COMMAND*/
            UPDATE wp_posts
            SET id = counter
            WHERE id = col_id;
            /*YOUR UPDATE COMMAND*/

            SET counter = counter + 1;

        END LOOP;

        CLOSE ORDER_CURSOR;
END
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure how to do what you requested. I have almost no knowledge on MySQL, so I need you to provide more detailed information. I don't know what you mean by `table_id`, and I'm not really sure if I need to add information like you requested, or if I should replace data in the script. My database name is `tests`, table name is `wp_posts`, and ID column name and type are `ID` and `BIGINT(20)`.

Comment: Just run the command I posted above in your database. Copy the whole code and insert it into the SQL-Query-Editor in phpmyadmin and run it. The script should do the rest.

What the scrip does is: It selects every row of your table and orders them by the date ascending so your ID fields get updated based on the publication date. Then it updates every row with a new ID.

Comment: No success, Nate :S I got the following error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE col_id BIGINT' at line 2`

Comment: OK. Then we have to store the command within a MySQL-Stored-Procedure and run it from there. Click on your Table in phpmyadmin. Now you can select different operation from the tabs in phpmyadmin (like the "SQL" tab). There should also be a tab Called "Routines". Click on it, and then "new Routine". Give it any name you want. Within the definition section paste my code above. Delete any Parameters phpmyadmin set by default in the window. Then click OK. Now go to your normal SQL-Query-Window and type `CALL your_name()`. Where "your_name" is the name you chose for the procedure.

Comment: I managed to do it, but now I'm getting the following error: `#1062 - Duplicate entry '6' for key 'PRIMARY' `

Comment: Thats because you already have some values for the primary key stored in your database. So before you run the my code you have to remove the Primary-Key dependancy and re-add it after you run my code. To do this: `ALTER TABLE wp_posts MODIFY id INT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE wp_posts DROP PRIMARY KEY;` Then run `your_name()`. Then re-add the Primary key: `ALTER TABLE wp_posts MODIFY id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL; ALTER TABLE wp_posts ADD PRIMARY KEY(id);`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your dedication and patience, Nate :) It took me quite a look time to test it, but it seems to be working fine. The only problem is that it took quite a long time to do it, so I had to shut it down after 10 hours of operating. Seems the problems with this method is that I have too many rows (more than 4 thousand). I checked the table after and it reached to almost half the table. Until that point at least, it seems it worked fine :)